# TensorFlow XLA with multiple gpu does not use GPU at the same time

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use XLA on multi GPU machine. bat when I turn on XLA JIT, tensorflow does not use GPU at the same time.

when XLA on, gpu0 and gpu1 be active alternately.

[image]

[image]

when XLA off, gpu0 and gpu1 are both active at same time.

[image]

what is happen on my environment?

## my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from pathlib import Path
import time

INPUT_SIZE = 64
INPUT_CHANNELS = 1
MINIBATCH_SIZE = 32
NUM_ITERATIONS = 200000
NUM_GPU = 2

def read_op(filename_queue, reader):
    _, raw = reader.read(filename_queue)

    read_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(
        raw, channels=INPUT_CHANNELS)
    read_image = tf.to_float(read_image) / 255.
    read_image = tf.image.resize_images(read_image, [INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE])
    return read_image

def inference(image, log_suffix):
    # autoencoder model for mutli GPU testing
    # this model has no particular meaning
    def w_init(initial_weight=1e-3):
        return tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=initial_weight)

    def make_conv(x, out_ch, stride=[1,1,1,1]):
        shape = x.get_shape().as_list()

        with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
            conv_w = tf.get_variable(initializer=w_init(), name='weight',
                shape=[7, 7, shape[3], out_ch])

        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, conv_w, stride, padding='SAME')
        mean, var = tf.nn.moments(conv, [0])
        conv = tf.nn.batch_normalization(conv, mean, var, None, None, 1e-9)

        return tf.nn.relu(conv)

    def make_deconv(x, out_shape, bn=True):
        shape = x.get_shape().as_list()

        with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
            w = tf.get_variable(initializer=w_init(), name='weight',
                shape=[7, 7, out_shape[3], shape[3]])

        deconv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(x, w, out_shape, [1,2,2,1])
        mean, var = tf.nn.moments(deconv, [0])

        if bn: deconv = tf.nn.batch_normalization(deconv, mean, var, None, None, 1e-9)

        return tf.nn.relu(deconv)

    def make_deconv_same(x, out_shape, activate=tf.nn.relu, bn=True, scale=1e-3):
        shape = x.get_shape().as_list()

        with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
            w = tf.get_variable(initializer=w_init(), name='weight',
                shape=[7, 7, out_shape[3], shape[3]])

        deconv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(x, w, out_shape, [1,1,1,1])
        mean, var = tf.nn.moments(deconv, [0])

        if bn: deconv = tf.nn.batch_normalization(deconv, mean, var, None, None, 1e-9)

        return activate(deconv)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
        conv1 = make_conv(image, 128)
    with tf.variable_scope('conv2'):
        conv2 = make_conv(conv1, 128)
    with tf.variable_scope('conv3'):
        conv3 = make_conv(conv2, 160, stride=[1,2,2,1])
    with tf.variable_scope('conv4'):
        conv4 = make_conv(conv3, 160)
    with tf.variable_scope('conv5'):
        conv5 = make_conv(conv4, 192, stride=[1,2,2,1])
    with tf.variable_scope('conv6'):
        conv6 = make_conv(conv5, 192)
    with tf.variable_scope('conv7'):
        conv7 = make_conv(conv6, 256, stride=[1,2,2,1])
    with tf.variable_scope('conv8'):
        conv8 = make_conv(conv7, 256)
    with tf.variable_scope('linear1'):
        feature_lengh = 300
        shape = conv8.get_shape().as_list()
        vec_length = shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]
        in_vec = tf.reshape(conv8,[-1, vec_length])

        with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
            w = tf.get_variable(initializer=w_init(1e-2), name='weight',
                shape=[vec_length, feature_lengh])
            b = tf.get_variable(initializer=w_init(1e-2), name='bias',
                shape=[feature_lengh])

        linear1 = tf.matmul(in_vec, w) + b
        mean, var = tf.nn.moments(linear1, [0])
        linear1 = tf.nn.batch_normalization(linear1, mean, var, None, None, 1e-9)
        linear1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(linear1)
    with tf.variable_scope('linear2'):
        in_shape = linear1.get_shape().as_list()
        in_length = in_shape[1]
        out_shape = conv8.get_shape().as_list()
        out_length = out_shape[1] * out_shape[2] * out_shape[3]

        with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
            w = tf.get_variable(initializer=w_init(1e-2), name='weight',
                shape=[in_length, out_length])
            b = tf.get_variable(initializer=w_init(1e-2), name='bias',
                shape=[out_length])

        linear2 = tf.matmul(linear1, w) + b
        mean, var = tf.nn.moments(linear2, [0])
        linear2 = tf.nn.batch_normalization(linear2, mean, var, None, None, 1e-9)
        linear2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(linear2)
        linear2 = tf.reshape(linear2, out_shape)
    with tf.variable_scope('deconv1'):
        deconv1 = make_deconv_same(linear2, conv7.get_shape())
    with tf.variable_scope('deconv2'):
        deconv2 = make_deconv     (deconv1, conv6.get_shape())
    with tf.variable_scope('deconv3'):
        deconv3 = make_deconv_same(deconv2, conv5.get_shape())
    with tf.variable_scope('deconv4'):
        deconv4 = make_deconv     (deconv3, conv4.get_shape())
    with tf.variable_scope('deconv5'):
        deconv5 = make_deconv_same(deconv4, conv3.get_shape())
    with tf.variable_scope('deconv6'):
        deconv6 = make_deconv     (deconv5, conv2.get_shape())
    with tf.variable_scope('deconv7'):
        deconv7 = make_deconv_same(deconv6, conv1.get_shape())
    with tf.variable_scope('deconv8'):
        deconv8 = make_deconv_same(deconv7, image.get_shape(), bn=False, scale=1e-1)

    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        image_log = tf.summary.image('output'+log_suffix, deconv8, collections=['image_log'])
        image_log = tf.summary.image('input'+log_suffix, image, collections=['image_log'])

    return deconv8

def loss(label, out, global_step, log_suffix):
    with tf.name_scope('loss'):
        l = tf.squared_difference(label, out)

        # for tensorboard Logarithmic graph mode
        lv = tf.reduce_mean(l) * 1e+7

        with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
            loss_log = tf.summary.scalar('loss'+log_suffix,lv)

    return l

def average_gradients(tower_grads):
    with tf.name_scope('avarage_gradients'):
        average_grads = []

        for grad_and_vars in zip(*tower_grads):
            grads = []

            for g, u in grad_and_vars:
                expanded_g = tf.expand_dims(g,0)
                grads.append(expanded_g)

            grad = tf.concat(grads, axis=0)
            grad = tf.reduce_mean(grad,0)

            v = grad_and_vars[0][1]
            grad_and_var = (grad, v)
            average_grads.append(grad_and_var)

        for grad,var in average_grads:
            with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                tf.summary.histogram('grads/'+var.name, grad, collections=['grads'])

    return average_grads

def main():
    global NUM_GPU, MINIBATCH_SIZE

    # many jpeg images
    sample_dir = Path('./training_samples')
    file_list = [p for p in sample_dir.iterdir() if p.suffix == '.jpg']
    file_list = list(map(str, file_list))

    with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        config_proto = tf.ConfigProto(
            allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=False)
        # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        # if XLA is on, problem occured
        # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        #config_proto.graph_options.optimizer_options.global_jit_level = tf.OptimizerOptions.ON_1
        sess = tf.Session( config=config_proto)

        global_step = tf.get_variable(
            'global_step', [], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)

        with tf.variable_scope('optimizer'):
            opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-6)

        with tf.variable_scope('input'):
            filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(file_list)
            reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
            images_list = [
                tf.train.shuffle_batch(
                    [read_op(filename_queue, reader)], MINIBATCH_SIZE, 24000, 8000, num_threads=8),
                tf.train.shuffle_batch(
                    [read_op(filename_queue, reader)], MINIBATCH_SIZE, 24000, 8000, num_threads=8)]

        tower_grads = []
        reuse = False
        for i in range(NUM_GPU):
            with tf.device('/gpu:{}'.format(i)):
                with tf.variable_scope('model', reuse=reuse, caching_device='/gpu:{}'.format(i)):
                    infer = inference(images_list[i], '/tower_{}'.format(i))
                    reuse = True
                    tower_loss = loss(images_list[i], infer, global_step, '/tower_{}'.format(i))

                grads = opt.compute_gradients(tower_loss)
                tower_grads.append( grads )

        grads = average_gradients(tower_grads)
        train_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)

        image_log_op = tf.summary.merge(tf.get_collection('image_log'))
        loss_log_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
        grads_log_op = tf.summary.merge(tf.get_collection('grads'))

        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs')
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())
        coordinator = tf.train.Coordinator()

        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coordinator)

        for i in range(NUM_ITERATIONS):
            print('iteration: ',i)

            start = time.time()

            if i % 2 == 0:
                _, loss_log, image_log = sess.run([train_op, loss_log_op, image_log_op])
                writer.add_summary(loss_log, i)
                writer.add_summary(image_log, i)
                writer.flush()
            else:
                _ = sess.run([train_op])

            end = time.time()

            print('time = {}'.format(end - start))

        writer.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Environment info

Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04
GPU : GTX 1080 x2
config option(gcc) : -march=native -O3
config option(cuda capability) : 6.1

Installed version of CUDA and cuDNN:

```
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudadevrt.a
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so -> libcudart.so.8.0
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0 -> libcudart.so.8.0.44
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0.44
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart_static.a
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so -> libcudnn.so.5.1.5
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.5 -> libcudnn.so.5.1.5
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.5.1.5
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn_static.a
```

The tensorflow commit hash c56c873fbaf976d26d487ad57c8efbc87f05331c

The output of `bazel version`

```
.......
Build label: 0.4.4
Build target: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Wed Feb 1 18:54:21 2017 (1485975261)
Build timestamp: 1485975261
Build timestamp as int: 1485975261
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, XLA is single GPU.

Comment: OK, I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't turn on JIT compilation at the session level. You should use jit_scope() to scope which part of the model should be included in XLA JIT compilation and this works at multiple GPU training. 
For more in details, you can refer to this link:
http://danny270degree.blogspot.com/2018/06/xla-jit-how-to-turn-on-xla-jit.html